# Trying to convert the time stamps in my dictionary to dates

Tags: python

```
 all_data = {}
for ticker in ['TWTR', 'SNAP', 'FB']:
      all_data[ticker] = np.array(pd.read_csv('https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?i=60&p=10d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v&df=cpct&q={}'.format(ticker, skiprows=7, header=None))


date = []

for i in np.arange(0, len(all_data['SNAP'])):
      if all_data['SNAP'][i][0][0] == 'a':
     t = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(all_data['SNAP'][i][0].replace('a','')))
     date.append(t)
    else:
        date.append(t+ datetime.timedelta(minutes= int(all_data['SNAP'][i][0])))
```

Hi, what this code does is to create a dictionary(all_data) and then put intraday data for twitter, snapchat, facebook into the dictionary from the url. The dates are in epoch time format and so the second for did a second for loop.

I was only able to do so for one of the tickers (SNAP) and i was wondering if anyone knew how to create iterate all the data to do the same

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis on the 3rd line.

Comment: @PedroLobito on the actual code I have the closing parenthesis, I just forgot to type it in here

Answer (score 0):

With `pandas`, you normally convert a `timestamp` to `datetime` using:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], unit="s")
```

---

Note:
Your script seems to contain other errors, which are outside the scope of the question.